# I getting this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversation exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I getting this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversation exists (are you missing a cast?) I am a bit rusty on C#. have not done much for about two years

I am to be writing this 
Write a console application that calculates the amount of income tax required based on filing status and
taxable income.
The program should prompt the user to enter either a filing status of Single or Married (or Quit). If
anything else is entered, an error message should be displayed and the input should be repeated.
If the status is either Single or Married, the taxable income is input and the amount of tax is printed.
This process should repeat until Quit is entered.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void gobutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal income  //hold income value
            decimal tax     //hold tax value  

            //get income value
            income = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);


            //Display the output ino the tax output label
            taxoutputlabel.Text = tax;

            if (textBox1.Text == "single")
                if (income <= 8700)
                    tax = income * 0.10;
                else if (income <= 35350)
                    tax = 4867.50 + (35350 - 8700) * 0.15;
                else if (income <= 85650)
                    tax = 17442.50 + (85650 - 35350) * 0.25;
                else if (income <= 178650)
                    tax = 43482.50 + (178650 - 85650) * 0.28;
                else if (income <= 388350)
                    tax = 112683.50 + (388350 - 178650) * 0.35;
            else if (textBox1.Text == "marriage, married")
                if (income <= 17400)
                        tax = income * 0.10;
                else if (income <= 70700)
                        tax = 4867.50 + (70700 - 17400) * 0.15;
                else if (income <= 142700)
                        tax = 17442.50 + (142700 - 70700) * 0.25;
                else if (income <= 217450)
                        tax = 43482.50 + (217450 -142700) * 0.28;
                else if (income <= 388350)
                        tax = 112683.50 + (388350 - 178650) * 0.35;
            else if (textBox1.Text == "divorced")
                if (income <= 8700)
                    tax = income * 0.10;
                else if (income <= 35350)
                    tax = 4867.50 + (35350 - 8700) * 0.15;
                else if (income <= 85650)
                    tax = 17442.50 + (85650 - 35350) * 0.25;
                else if (income <= 178650)
                    tax = 43482.50 + (178650 - 85650) * 0.28;
                else if (income <= 388350)
                    tax = 112683.50 + (388350 - 178650) * 0.35;

        }

        private void exitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //closes form
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind pointing out exactly *where* the error is happening?

Comment: any where "tax =" is and  taxoutputlabel.Text = tax; has the same error

Comment: try `tax = income * 0.10m`;

Comment: Also the code doesn't even compile. `decimal income //hold income value` without semicolon at end et cetera. Please be more cautious about these errors when asking questions.

Comment: Thank you, as I did say i have been out of coding for about two years. Sorry for missing that. I knew was something simple.

Comment: Linked duplicate explains the reason of the error message. If you need help with C# syntax SO is somewhat wrong place to ask about it.

Comment: idk helped me so far :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler treats 0.10 (and any other fractions) as a `double` by default.

To tell the compiler that it is a decimal, you have to use the `m` suffix like this:

```
tax = income * 0.10m;
```

You have to do this for all numbers used in the equations. For example:

```
tax = 4867.50m + (35350m - 8700m) * 0.15m;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. taxoutputlabel.Text = tax; has the error of cannot implicity convert type Decimal to string.

Comment: use `tax.ToString()`.

Comment: taxoutputlabel.Text = tax.ToString(); now says use of unassigned local variable 'tax'

Comment: @MatthewHunt that means you need to `Initialize` it to a value for example `var tax = 0.0;`

Comment: @MethodMan, if OP wants to use `var`, then he should initialize it as `0.0m` so that the compiler knows it is a decimal.

Comment: I know @YacoubMassad basically what I was stating is that the  compiler was complaining because just doing `decimal tax;` the compiler expects it to be initialized

Comment: @YacoubMassad .ToString() will not solve your compile issues, it will only introduce another issue since tax is repeatedly used in the code further down.

Comment: thank you all soo much. That helped!!! when you dont use this stuff you really forgot it

Comment: @Chrotenise, I am not really sure what you mean. I advised OP to use `taxoutputlabel.Text = tax.ToString()` to set the value of the label.

Comment: @YacoubMassad it is/was not clear you're refering to Matthew Hunt's comment. I would edit that in your comment for easier reading.

Comment: You all are great. I have no more error! Though now I am getting 0 returned back to me each time I run the program.

Comment: You should set `taxoutputlabel.Text` after you are doing with the calculations, not before.

Comment: sigh... I feel like a nube all over again. thank you so much. I knew something was out of place. Just did not know what.

Answer (score 4):

Simply convert to decimal would not resolve?

```
tax = Convert.ToDecimal(4867.50 + (70700 - 17400) * 0.15);
```